# In the Unearthed Arcana ranger, can "humanoid" (in general) be your Favored Enemy?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, unearthed-arcana

Just some clarification: when choosing a favoured enemy (using the Unearthed Arcana rules), can a ranger choose "Humanoid" in general, so use the bonus for all humanoids?

I have read it this way (hitting an orc or elf in the privates or the heart will hurt it pretty much the same). I have just come across another DM who will only allow one type of humanoid.

> Choose a type of favored enemy: beasts, fey, humanoids, monstrosities, or undead. You gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with weapon attacks against creatures of the chosen type.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### [UA Revised Ranger](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf) would allow "humanoid" as a general selection. (The first UA ranger had no favored enemy.)

PHB rangers specified that a ranger needed to choose only some races of humanoid for their favored enemy:

> aberrations, beasts, celestials, constructs, dragons, elementals, fey, fiends, giants, monstrosities, oozes, plants, or undead. Alternatively, you can *select two races of humanoid*. (PHB p.91, emphasis mine)

The revision specifically removes that limitation on humanoids:

> Choose    a   type    of  favored enemy:  beasts, fey, humanoids, monstrosities,  or  undead. (UA Revised Ranger)

#### Finally, humanoids don't have "types," "humanoid" *is* a type.

See MM p.6.